# Как взять роли нескольких профилей с помощью запроса, чтобы роли не повторялись в 1С?

Tags: 1с

Есть список профилей доступа. Мне нужно получить роли, которые в них лежат. И надо сделать так, чтобы роли не повторялись в массиве с результатом. Но как это можно сделать?

Сейчас у меня есть запрос, который получает массив с одним профилем из базы 1С. Один профиль просто для теста. Как выбрать несколько профилей я понимаю. Еще, чтобы в результате были различные варианты, вроде, можно после `ВЫБРАТЬ` написать `РАЗЛИЧНЫЕ`. Но как взять не профили, а их роли?

```
ВЫБРАТЬ
|   ПрофилиГруппДоступа.Ссылка КАК Ссылка
|ИЗ
|   Справочник.ПрофилиГруппДоступа КАК ПрофилиГруппДоступа
|ГДЕ
|   ПрофилиГруппДоступа.Наименование = ""Администратор""
```

Если просто написать `ПрофилиГруппДоступа.Роли КАК Роли` вместо `ПрофилиГруппДоступа.Ссылка КАК Ссылка`, то возвращается что-то не то. Какая-то таблица значений, в которой я не могу найти роли.

И еще в таком случае, если выбрано `n` профилей, то вернется `n` массивов с ролями. А это не подходит, потому что в таком случае могут попасться одинаковые роли.

Comment: Книга "Язык запросов «1С:Предприятия 8», 2-е стереотипное издание" Хрусталева.
Ссылки:
1. [Как хранятся данные в «1С:Предприятии»](https://its.1c.ru/db/pubqlang#content:6:1)
2. [https://its.1c.ru/db/pubqlang#content:25:1](https://its.1c.ru/db/pubqlang#content:25:1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
|ВЫБРАТЬ РАЗЛИЧНЫЕ
|   ТаблицаРолейПрофиля.Роль КАК Роль
|ИЗ
|   Справочник.ПрофилиГруппДоступа.Роли КАК ТаблицаРолейПрофиля
|ГДЕ
|   ТаблицаРолейПрофиля.Ссылка В (&Профили)
```